# php отказывается видеть подгруженные js'ом формы

Tags: php, jquery

Есть страница загрузки файлов с таким кодом:

```
    echo '<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Файлы:<br /><div id="upload">
  <input name=userfile[] type=file><br>
  <input name=userfile[] type=file><br>
  <input name=userfile[] type=file><br>
  <input name=userfile[] type=file><br>
  <input name=userfile[] type=file><br>
  </div><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
<div id="continue">Добавить еще</div><br>';

echo '</div>
<script>
var i = 0;
$("#continue").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); console.log(i);
if(i<=14){
    var txt = "<input name=userfile[] type=file><br>";
    i++;
    $("#upload").append(txt);
}
if(i == 15){
    $("#continue").remove();
}
})
</script>';
```

и есть обработчик:

```
 $path = 'upload/';
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['userfile']); $i++){
    if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i])){
        echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i].' \ '.$i.'<br>';
        copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path . $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]);
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что обработчик не видит добавленные посредством JS формы загрузки. Прошу помощи)

Comment: на клиенте элементы input добавляются ?

Comment: Да. Вопрос решен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте этот скрипт, все работает. просто надо сделать `count($_FILES['userfile']['name'])`

```
$path = 'upload/';
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++){
   if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i])){
    echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i].' \ '.$i.'<br>';
    copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path . $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо